# Need to install Pro SKU version of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-8-preview, visual-studio, windows-8

I asked this on the msdn Visual Studio forum, but (thanks to superuser and stackoverflow, etc.), it seems that place has become the Bodie of the Interwebs; so, I will ask the question here:

I have the trial edition (139 days left!) of VS 2012 Express installed ("Visual Studio 2012 Express RC for Windows 8" - why the Express version has a time limit, I don't know - maybe because it's pre-release?).

I want to purchase the Pro SKU of Visual Studio 2012. How should I proceed - first uninstall the Express trial? And from where (link) should I install the Pro SKU?

The blog post that I recently read about its availability -- by Sammy Sosa or some name like that -- seemed to cover every possible scenario (msdn subscriber, high-volume corporate purchasers, students, etc.) but mine: an independent developer with the express trial version wanting to update to the Pro SKU.

Similarly, I will need to install the "real" version of Windows 8 when it becomes available - currently have the Release Preview installed. Does anybody know the steps for that - can I just upgrade "in place" or what? Currently, Windows 8 Release Preview is the only OS I have installed on my laptop...???

Comment: Yes, the time limit is because it is not the final release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, the Pro version and the express versions are supposed to be able to co-exist side-by-side on the same machine without interfering with one another.  That being said, all you would have to do is install the Pro version.  However, I would recommend that uninstall the Express RC version first.  If you have Pro, there really isn't much reason to keep the express edition around on the same machine and you'll need to uninstall the Express RC anyway if you want to install the final Express edition later.

The bigger question is the Windows 8 upgrade from RP to RTM/Final.  Officially, from Microsoft, this is not supported and you will have to install the RTM/Final version as a "new" installation if the previous version is a Win8 preview edition.  However, there have been those who say that [you can still do it](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9230479/Bloggers_show_how_to_upgrade_Windows_8_previews_to_RTM).  If that's the case, you won't lose anything.  But as it isn't officially supported by MS, I would probably just backup my files and install it clean.